# Update portion of the website using Ajax form call

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to show an error message when there is an error when performing a POST form request using Ajax (I don't want the page to refresh). However, the code bellow  does not change - it still shows "NO ERRORS" although the `TempData["Error]` variable is not null (it's set in the controller's action). What I am doing wrong?

That is my **_Layout.cshtml** (I want to be able to show this error message from every page)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
@*@RenderBody()*@
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div id="divEmp">

    @if (TempData["Error"] != null)
    {
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">"Error here"</div>
    }
    else
    {
        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">NO ERRORS</div>
    }

</div>

@RenderSection("BodyFill", false)
@RenderBody()
@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

That is my **Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult ShareWorkbook(string emails, string title, string id, string queryBuilderId)
{   
    TempData["Error"] = Res.System_Error_Message;
    return NoContent();
}
```

That is my **form** (it's located in a partial view and injected at runtime in the main page)

```
@using DNAAnalysisCore.Resources
@model DNAAnalysisCore.Models.WorkbookShareModel
@* Partial view that contains the 'Share Workbook dialog' modal *@

<!-- Modal -->
<div onclick="activateShareButtons()" class="modal fade" id="shareFormModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Share Workbook - @Model.Title</h4>

            </div>

            <form id="partialform" asp-action="ShareWorkbook" asp-controller="Home" method="post" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-update="divEmp">
                <div class="modal-body">
                ...
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button onclick="hideDialog()" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Share</button>
                    <button onclick="activateShareButtons()" id="btnCancelDialog" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not null? Did you put a breakpoint in the `Layout` page, on that if?

Comment: @jpgrassi I put break points both in the if and else statements. They were not hit at all when I performed the post (I did 2 post requests). However, I saw the "Error here" when I refreshed the page after I've done the above using Ctrl + F5. The break points were hit then

Comment: Yeah, that was my suspicion. Since this is an XHR request, the page isn't reloaded so your layout page is never executed. You'll need to handle the error in your `activateShareButtons` and somehow display the errors, I'm afraid.

Comment: That's fine. Thank you for confirming that. I am will what I can do :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly modify the HTML markups using javascript in callback function of Ajax .I assume in your _Layout.cshtml :

```
<div id="divEmp">
    <div id="showError" style="display:none;"  class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">"Error here"</div>
    <div id="noError" style="display:none;" class="alert alert-success" role="alert">NO ERRORS</div>
</div>
```

In your page you will use ajax to call server side function , and depend on response you can directly show/modify above area :

```
$(function () {
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: '/Home/GetJobData',
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      success: function (response) {

          if (response.success) {
              $("#showError").hide();
              $("#noError").show();
          }
          else {
              $("#showError").show();
              $("#noError").hide();
              $("#showError").text(response.responseText);
          }
      },
      error: function (response) {
          alert("error!");
      }
  });
})
```

Server side function :

```
public IActionResult GetJobData()
{
    var isFileSupported = true;
    if (!isFileSupported)
    {
        //  Send "false"
        return Json(new { success = false, responseText = "Your operation fail !" });
    }
    else
    {
        //  Send "Success"
        return Json(new { success = true, responseText = "Your operation Success !" });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Nan Yu. That looks really good and I was considering something like that. However, I need that Ajax call to be executed when I press the "submit" button of the form. Is this possible?

Comment: @GeorgiKoemdzhiev , your submit button is html button like : <button type = "button" onclick="postdata()"> subimit</button> ? Then just move the ajax code to postdata javscript function

Comment: Thanks! I suppose this method will "hijack" the form's original post method (i.e. the post won't be executed twice?)

Comment: @GeorgiKoemdzhiev You are using the Ajax to post data , doesn't with the [form's submit ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-2.2) , so why it will fire twice ?

Comment: It was just a thought, I am new to web dev. Also, I forgot that I was using the ajax form  - previously I was using the Http.BeginForm tag helper which produces a synchronous post.

Comment: @GeorgiKoemdzhiev Yes , with form tag , it will submit and refresh whole page , but it doesn't happen with ajax post :)